# Insert into a table with the data present in one table which match the first row of another table

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am new to sql.

I want to insert a data to backup table from main table that also matches the first record of another table.

suppose I have backup table with name "baktble" and main table with name "sales".
note : both tables have same columns c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6.

and I have a buffer table "buftble" with columns only the first 3 columns of bakup and sales table c1,c2,c3.

Now how to insert a data into backup table from sales table which matches the columns of first record.

I tired this but got error.

```
insert into baktble 
    select * 
    from sales 
    where col1,col2,col3 in (
         select top 1 col1,col2,col3 
         from buftble).
```

Comment: the proper form is `where (col1,col2,col3) in (select top 1 col1,col2,col3 from buftble)`

Comment: I have tried it its working fine thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So while nbk's as is the correct SQL syntax for your query:

```
create table baktble(col1 int, col2 int, col3 int, col4 int, col5 int, col6 int);
create or replace table sales(col1 int, col2 int, col3 int, col4 int, col5 int, col6 int);
create or replace table buftble(col1 int, col2 int, col3 int);

insert into buftble values
    (1,10,100),
    (2,20,200),
    (3,30,300);

insert into sales values
    (1,10,100, 101, 102, 103),
    (2,20,200, 201, 202, 203),
    (3,30,300, 301, 302, 303);

insert into baktble 
    select * 
    from sales
    where (col1,col2,col3) in (
         select top 1 col1,col2,col3 
         from buftble);
```

this only ever inserts zero or one row from sales into baktble.

Because the `top 1` only selects one row from `buftble`

If I had to guess what you are wanting to do is ether:

- insert all sales that match the distinct rows in buftble
- insert the first sales row that matches the distinct rows in buftble

The first is done with:

```
insert into baktble 
    select * 
    from sales
    where (col1,col2,col3) in (
         select distinct col1,col2,col3 
         from buftble);
```

and the later (with the assumption that col4 is valid to sort duplicate values by) using QUALIFY and ROW_NUMBER like so:

```
insert into baktble 
    select * 
    from sales
    where (col1,col2,col3) in (
         select distinct col1,col2,col3 
         from buftble)
    qualify row_number() over (partition by col1,col2,col3 order by col4 desc) = 1;
```